# Split a string and save with has_and_belongs_to_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a text_field which the user can type in Tags(Like the ones on stackoverflow). They can seperate the tags with a comma. Now, I know how to split the tags. But the n00b that I am I'm stuck at the next stage. I have a Tag table, a Trip table and a tags_trips in between(A trip can have multiple keywords, but I want the keywords unique in my database so when they exist they can be used again on other Trips).

The real question is; After I've split the string, how can I check if the keyword exists and get the existing ID to be placed in my tags_trips table, and if it doesn't exist how do i get the array I've just split in my tags_trips table in one go?

Here's an overview of my tables:

```
Trip
:id => :integer,
:title => :string,
:description => :text,
:user_id => :integer,
:created_at => :datetime,
:updated_at => :datetime

Tag
:id => :integer,
:title => :string,
:created_at => :datetime,
:updated_at => :datetime

tags_trip
:tag_id => :integer,
:trip_id => :string
```

I'm using a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association between Tag and Trip in my models and get the text_field via `fields_for :tags` in my Trip form. (Note: The form works and I've managed to get the keywords string, as it is typed, into my Tag table! Just not split up ;-))

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. I'm not sure if it's the best way, but it works! This is what I've done:
I loop through the params[:trip][:tag_attributes] if present. And loop through it again whilst splitting it on a comma. Than in the loop i do a `find_or_create_by` on the trip.tags and Voila! they're saved. After that i delete the tags_attributes from the params[:trip] so it won't be saved on the update_Attributes. ChuckE, you've been a fantastic help, thanks a million!

Code:

```
def update
    @trip = Trip.find(params[:id])

    if params[:trip][:tags_attributes].present?
      params[:trip][:tags_attributes].each do |tag| 
       @a = tag[1]['title']
       @a.split(',').each do |single|
          @trip.tags.create(:title => single)  
       end
      end
    end

    #Delete the tags attributes from the trip array so it will not be saved.
    params[:trip].delete('tags_attributes')
    respond_to do |format|
      if @trip.update_attributes(params[:trip])
      format.html { redirect_to @trip, notice: 'Trip was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
      else
       format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @trip.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: glad to help, eheh. Just one more thing: that :tags_attributes field means you are using fields_for helper (which you are, I just re-read the question, shame on me for not noticing). So, all that crap I told you previously to have a tags= method in your trip model, you can rewrite it as tags_attributes=, then you can move your above logic (line 4-14) to the model, and therefore get a cleaner controller.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the title of your tags to be unique throughout your aplication, you need to set an index of uniqueness on the table. Besides that, the has_and_belongs_to_many has an :uniq field, which when set to true, will ignore repetitions. If that still doesn't do the trick, try using find_or_create_by_title helper when creating your tags.

Comment: I think that answers a part of my question (I'll try it when I figured out the complete answer) because I don't know how i can save a split up string to my Tags table and make it associate with my Trips automatically. Note: The way i save my Trip now is just the basic `@trip = Trip.new(params[:trip])`. I'm assuming this doesn't apply anymore if i want some of the params(The tagfield) to be changed/manipulated first.

Comment: to automatically associate, you can to this: @trip = Trip.new(params[:trip]); @trip.tags.find_or_create_by_title("zing")  or @trip.tags.find_or_initialize_by_title("zing"), depending of what you want. check the documentation for the collection association methods here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Forgive my stupidity but I'm really not getting it. When I use your code (Yes, i used Zing because it shouldn't matter for test purposes i  guess?) the tags are just beings saved through `@trip = Trip.new(params[:trip])` and nothing seems to change after that.

Comment: maybe I understood the question wrong. Didn't you want to create and associate tags directly on your @trip variable?

Comment: Pretty much. The user can create a string of tags divided by a comma. I want to split those up so the string becomes a list of words. Those words should be saved in my Tag table and be associated with my Trip. So basically the same you would do with multiple categories on a trip but with the splitting+saving in between that i don't get :-)

Comment: you have to get the string of tags, split them by ',', and for each, @trip.tags.create(:title => tag).

Comment: Thanks, i can't try it out right now but it seems plausible. The text_field i have to strip is in the @trip form though, so when i'm saving the params the tags-string is saved too. Can i exclude it somehow?

Comment: You probably mean the tags string coming from the form is somewhere stored on a key inside params[:trip]. I'd have to know its name to provide you with a clean way to abstract this attribution.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have the code at hand at this time. It is however a simple text_field within my Trip form. (A `fields_for @tags` in my `form_for @trip`)

Comment: so, if the tags are in params[:trip][:tags], and you mass-assign using Trip.new(params[:trip]), then you need in the trip model this:

Comment: def tags=(tags) ; tags.is_a?(String) ? self.tags.find_or_create_by_name(*tags.split(',')) : super

Comment: I've got the feeling that I must do a little more than just adding that line(You forgot an `end` by the way). Because it stills saves along with the `params[:trip]` as a single string.

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to indent the code in the comments section, lost track. Anyway, what I'm saying is, you can do the handling of it inside the model itself, provided you have an implementation for it when the tags are a string. http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/7/19/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-models it's more or less this.

Comment: Aye aye aye my n00bness doesn't help at all. I don't understand what you're trying to say with your last post. I've added your line to my Trips.rb and didn't solve anything. Is there another call or something i have to make to get that bloody thing to work? Because for now it just posts the string of my text field fully into the database.

Comment: Please see my answer, ChuckE.